# propertyGrid where some properties are Collection

Tags: c#, winforms, observablecollection, windows-forms-designer

I use ProperyGrid in windows form .net framework 4.8.
I use some property as ObservableCollection.
My project is almost correct but when I modify an item in ObservableCollection by Collection Editor window, CollectionChanged event run too many. Run a Clear event and as many as Add Event that count of my list final elements number.
How could I prevent it just run once at end run.

So if I will have a 7 elements -> "continue" in Clear and Add 1st, ... Add 6th element, and run an event when added 7th element finally.

I starting use ObservableCollection or some probe with IBindingList.
I would like run an event when collecton property editing ended but property change event just run for single properties.
So I would like use an event - this part is OK - and I need call this when collection added new item, removed item or edited item.

- with that option too: on Collection editor there can cancel modify so if canceled maybe could cancel modified.

Comment: Did you check if you are registering to `CollectionChanged` multiple times? eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/v2ck3J | compared to only registering once https://dotnetfiddle.net/HZe1tI